# Code First Entity Framework 4 : Failing with SQL Authentication

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, ctp

I'm working with Entity Framework 4 and CTP 4 and am really liking it so far.  I can get it working correctly when I'm using Windows Authentication to connect to the database but when I switch to SQL Authentication it fails with the message below.  I've  given the user a sysadmin role and it's default database is master.

Error:

> This operation requires a connection
>   to the 'master' database. Unable to
>   create a connection to the 'master'
>   database because the original database
>   connection has been opened and
>   credentials have been removed from the
>   connection string. Supply an unopened
>   connection.

Any ideas?

... some more error detail:

```
[InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +344
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.DbDatabaseExists(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +231
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DatabaseExists() +84
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseOperations.Exists(ObjectContext objectContext) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Database.Exists() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +129
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializer>b__0(DbContext c) +75
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Database.Initialize() +207
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +70
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext() +9
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) +51
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) +17
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +24
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.EfInternalQuery`1.Initialize() +62
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.EfInternalQuery`1.get_Provider() +9
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +13
   System.Linq.Queryable.Select(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector) +63
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
   Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

Thanks to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/870959ef-5c06-4c3e-b9f8-454346592280

Comment: Just goes to show how 'beta' this EF actually is. 'and am really liking it so far' scares me a lot.

Comment: Except if you actually DO want drop if model changes, or drop always... this (null) caller makes it set to CreateIfNotExists, always.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the following exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'

Entity Framework 4.1 Update 1 contains a bug fix to remove the need to specify ‘Persist Security Info=True’ in the connection string when using SQL authentication.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26825